# Could not find "client" in the context or props of Mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

After executing my React Native app I've ran into this error:
`Could not find "client" in the context or props of Mutation. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance via props.`

Here's my apollo client

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

// To access our host machine and not the device itself we use a special ip on android
// If we are using IOS access localhost:4000 else use 10.0.0.2:4000
const host =
  Platform.OS === "ios" ? "http://localhost:4000" : "http://10.0.2.2:4000";

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: host,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

And here's index.tsx which wraps my root component:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { client } from "./apollo";
import { Routes } from "./routes/index";

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Routes />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before V 3.0 `react-apollo` and `apollo-client` (And other sub-packages) were on separate packages (Made a lot of issues/errors related to packages versions. [Issue 2042](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2042) -or- [issue 2900](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2900)).

The best idea is to Migrating to **Apollo Client 3.0**.

> The react-apollo package has been **deprecated**, and the functionality
> offered by each of the above packages can now be accessed from
> @apollo/client. [Migrating to Apollo Client 3.0](http://%20https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/)

**Apollo V3.0** Great "get-started"/tuturial example + sandbox:

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/

### client

In your case looks like the `client` is undefined. Run and test:

```
console.log(client); /* return object -or- not? */
```

Try to run this code in one file (If this code works fine - separate the files you want and use `module.exports`).

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
ApolloClient,
InMemoryCache,
ApolloProvider,
useQuery,
gql
} from "@apollo/client";


export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io",
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});


export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <h2>My first Apollo app <span></span></h2>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I've updated the code to use `@apollo/client`, though I am still getting the same error. Could `Routes` be related to it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to.